# Incorrect universal time format in input in dynamics CRM 365

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

In my Crm solution, I have changed a Date time behaviour to time zone independent.
[image]
I am trying to create a record of that entity from c# service code.

```
campaignResponseToSave.startdate = dateTimeStamp;
```

Sdk create method is throwing an error as incorrect universal time provided in input.

Does anyone have idea what could be wrong in this?

Comment: The error message is very explicit in this case.  The app is expecting the DateTime in a different format than what you are providing.  It looks like you are using a database so it may be you are passing a string to the database when you should be converting the string to a DateTime.  Another possibility is the country/language is wrong.  You may need to use the DateTime.ParseExact() method to convert the string date to a DateTime object.

Comment: Even if I pass DateTime.Now it is failing.

Comment: What is the database column type?

Comment: Did you try DateTime.UtcNow ?

Answer (score 1):

Time zone independent means you cannot have a time zone. All dates will have one by the default. You can use DateTime.ToUniversalTime() to achieve this. Like so:

```
string ds = "2007-10-04T00:00:00-04:00";
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(ds).ToUniversalTime();
```